# Undefined index even with the name is correct

Tags: php, post

I have added a file type input in my form named it "image" and the form has for a POST the link to a code and this is the relevant part:

```
$file=$_FILES['image'];
$name=$file['name'];
```

The problem I get is:

> Undefined index: image in C:\wamp\www\agence\ajoutoffre.php

I have checked a thousand of times the name of the input, it's right the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and `method="POST"` as attributes of the `<form>` element. Defaults are `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and `method="GET"` respectively, which are not suitable for file uploads.

Comment: If this does not work, show the HTML of the form that you use for uploading the image.